# VBA Copying Range from Other Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to copy the last 3 cells of Range A and then paste them into a new sheet called Report. Keep getting a compile error: Invalid or unqualified reference. I know the paste code is working but my copy code does not. Is it because .Cells requires it in a With loop? If so, I can't figure out how to correct it. This is the code in question:

```
Sheets("DATA").Activate

With Sheets("DATA")
    ' Use this lRow now since the previous ones require you to be in a With loop
    Range(.Cells(lRow - 2, 2), .Cells(lRow, 2)).Copy
End With

With Sheets("Report")
    .Activate
    ' Pastes the last 3 cells of Column A into the Month column
    .Range("B13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
    .Range("B12").Formula = "Month"
    .Range("C12").Formula = "Production Cost"
    'Calculates the production cost and places it in the correct column

    .Range("D12").Formula = "Inventory Cost"
    .Range("E12").Formula = "Total Cost"
    .Range("B16").Formula = "Total"
 End With
```

Comment: `Range(.Cells(lRow - 2, 2), .Cells(lRow, 2)).Copy` has no meaning except the case it is inside a `With ... End With` loop... Try `Range(Cells(lRow - 2, 2), Cells(lRow, 2)).Copy`. But the best idea is to better define the range, using its sheet. Something like that: `Dim shDat as Worksheet` followed by `Set shDat = Sheets("DATA")`. Then, no need to activate. You can use it like `shData.Range(shData.Cells(lRow - 2, 2), shData.Cells(lRow, 2)).Copy`. Activating, Selecting must be avoided except the cases when it is not possible to do that. Now, it is possible and recommended...

Comment: No need of `Sheets("Report").Activate` also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code `Range(.Cells(lRow - 2, 2), .Cells(lRow, 2)).Copy` isn't within a [With] statement, therefore the [.Cells] reference will be invalid.

Comment: If you just lose the ```.``` in ```.Cells``` that should do it...

Comment: Wow that was simple... it was 2am and yeah. Thank you!